# Batch file to merge many excel files in one, but copy them in order of the date modified

Tags: excel, batch-file, merge

So I'm trying to merge many excel files and .csv files in one directory into one .csv file. I use the following code:

```
> echo off
> 
> copy /a *.* merged.csv
> 
> end
```

And it works just fine but when it merges the files it does it in an alphabetical order which is inconvenient for me. Is there a way to merge them in the order that they were last modified? And if this is not possible, is it at least possible to create a batch file that takes all the names of the files and copies them into their first cell(the A1 cell)? Ex: If the file is named 01-01-2014.xls the name "01-01-2014" to appear in the A1 cell of the file(and this to be done for all the files in the directory). Note: The A1 cell is always empty(if it matters). Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /b /o:d /A:-D "C:\YourDir\" ') do type "C:\YourDir\%i">> merged.csv & echo.>> merged.csv
```

More details [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/227256-using-dos-commands-merge-txt-files-date.html).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I start the file nothing happens. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open a notepad file,

write:- copy **.csv Master.csv

save as batch file & run the file...result will appear soon.